# Align three elements with RelativeLayout

Tags: android

I'm trying to align three elements, the first at left edge (Imageview), in the center a Textview as a tittle and to the right edge a Imageview.

This is the code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:background="@color/fondo_main"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/buttonback"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:src="@drawable/back" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tittle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="Tittle"
        android:textColor="@color/azul_asde"
            android:src="@drawable/upload" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/buttonupload"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/upload" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

How can I align tittle at center?

Comment: you might wanna have a look at my updated answer. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

put this inside Textview

```
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/fondo_main"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/buttonback"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:src="@drawable/back" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tittle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/buttonback"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/buttonupload"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/upload"
            android:text="Tittle"
            android:textColor="@color/azul_asde" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/buttonupload"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/upload" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can align them using `toRightOf` and `toLeftOf` properties. try this

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tittle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:toRightOf="@id/buttonback"
    android:toLeftOf="@+id/buttonupload"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:maxLines="**YOUR CHOCICE**"
    android:text="Tittle"
    android:textColor="@color/azul_asde"
    android:src="@drawable/upload" />
```

**[EDIT]** Using both `toRightOf` and `toLeftOf` ensures that even if the text in the `EditText` is too long then the `buttonupload` on the right **will not shift outside the screen**.

*this is something you cant achieving using* `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"`*

**[NOTE]** you might also wanna consider `android:singleLine="false"` and `android:maxLines` properties.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/buttonback"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/tittle"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tittle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:text="Tittle"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/buttonupload"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tittle"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```